# How to keep application sessions seperate on same domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have been working on a problem for about a month now in regards to JWT authentication. I have multiple Asp.net MVC 4.5 applications using Owin that are deployed on the same machine and have different subdomains using IIS with an integrated pipeline. My problem is that when I log in to one application and browse to another application it does not re-authenticate and automatically allows the user to pass the authorization filter.

I have tried setting the cookie policy to strict and the cookie domain, path and name to different values and am unable to resolve this problem.

I have one custom Authentication Library that each of these applications use. I hope you can help.

What I would like to happen is that each application maintain its own authentication session and just because the user authenticated against the AD domain, it requires the user to reauthorize to make sure they have access to a particular application.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      CookieName = $"{tenantId}{clientId}"
 })
   .UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(GetAuthenticationOptions(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret));

private static OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions GetAuthenticationOptions(string clientId, string tenantId, string clientSecret)
{
     return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
     {
          MetadataAddress = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", tenantId),
          ClientId = clientId,
          ClientSecret = clientSecret,
          ResponseType = "id_token token",
          Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com",
          UseTokenLifetime = true,
          AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
          Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
          {
               SecurityTokenValidated = SecurityTokenValidated
          },
          TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
               NameClaimType = "mailNickName",
          }
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "cookieName" attribute of the "sessionState" XML element in your web.config to different values for each of your applications. That will keep them from using the same session ID.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="id" />
</system.web>
```

[sessionState Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Jalpa, I will introduce this and see if this resolved my problem.

Comment: Hi jalpa. Sorry it has not. It appears that somehow a aspnet.cookies is being created even though I have specified the cookie name to be a guid.